# Como verificar colisão entre partículas?

Tags: c++, qt, detecção-de-colisão

Preciso saber como fazer com que cada círculo se colida com o outro juntamente com a parte de como vou fazer para seguirem tal direção após essa colisão.

Essa é a classe da janela principal do programa:

```
class canvas : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit canvas(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent) {
        m_particulas.resize(30);
        int n = m_particulas.size();
        for(int i = 0 ; i<n ; ++i) {
            m_particulas[i].init();
        }
        startTimer(5);
    }
protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) {
        QPainter painter(this);
        painter.setWindow(0,0,1000,1000);
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);
        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::black, 5, Qt::SolidLine, Qt::RoundCap));
        painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt::darkCyan, Qt::SolidPattern));
        int n = m_particulas.size();
        for(int i = 0 ; i<n ; ++i) {
            double x = m_particulas[i].x();
            double y = m_particulas[i].y();
            double L = 2*m_particulas[i].r();
            painter.drawEllipse(QPointF(x, y), L, L);
        }
    }
    void timerEvent(QTimerEvent *) {
        int n = m_particulas.size();
        for(int i = 0 ; i<n ; ++i) {
            m_particulas[i].andar();
        }
        update();
    }
signals:
public slots:
private:
    std::vector<Particula> m_particulas;
};
```

E essa é a classe de cada partícula na tela:

```
class Particula {
private:
    double m_x;
    double m_y;
    double m_vx;
    double m_vy;
    double m_r;
public:
    Particula() {};
    void init() {
        m_r = 10;
        m_x = 900.0*rand()/RAND_MAX + 50;
        m_y = 900.0*rand()/RAND_MAX + 50;
        m_vx = 2.0 * rand()/RAND_MAX - 1;
        m_vy = 2.0 * rand()/RAND_MAX - 1;
        double norma = sqrt(m_vx*m_vx + m_vy*m_vy);
        m_vx /= norma;
        m_vy /= norma;
    }
    double x() const { return m_x; }
    double y() const { return m_y; }
    double r() const { return m_r; }
    void andar() {
        m_x += m_vx;
        m_y += m_vy;
        if(m_x > 990-m_r) m_vx *= -1; //inferior - multiplicado por -1 para inverter a direção...
        if(m_y > 990-m_r) m_vy *= -1; //direita
        if(m_x < 30-m_r) m_vx *= -1; //esquerda
        if(m_y < 30-m_r) m_vy *= -1; //superior
    }
};
```

Comment: 1. Se sua pergunta necessita de um link externo para ser compreendida, ela está extensa demais para o formato do SO. É importante que todos os elementos para a pergunta estejam na pergunta e que código, quando necessário, **não** seja o projeto inteiro, apenas a parte relevante. 2. Qual é a pergunta? Que problema e que dificuldade você ao tentar solucionar o seu problema? Onde está o ponto de interrogação da sua postagem?

Comment: Acho que você não leu o que escrevi, e certamente não sabe como funciona o QT Creator, pois não se trata de apenas um código para o programa funcionar e sim vários, por isso add o link contendo o arquivo compactado com os códigos.

Comment: Li sua pergunta e uso o QtCreator como principal IDE. No entando ainda não sei qual é a sua dúvida. Que problema você tem? No formato atual não há uma boa resposta sem resolver tuda a atividade por você.

Comment: É, a pergunta parece ser muito ampla. Se você não tem um problema específico, fica difícil responder. E o @GuilhermeBernal manja muito de Qt Creator. Não deu para entender o problema extamente mas dúvido que seja relacionado com o Qt Creator. E QT Creator nem é o nome correto da IDE da Qt. QT é abreviação de QuickTime.

Comment: No código atual, os círculos passam um por dentro do outro, e eu preciso fazer com que eles se choquem uns com os outros e voltem a direções opostas.

Comment: Certo. E qual é exatamente o problema que você teve? Não teve como pegar a posição dos circulos? Não sabe calcular se dois círculos colidem? Não tem certeza de o que fazer caso colidam? Não faz ideia de como mudar a direção de movimento deles? Ou você conseguiu fazer tudo isso e o resultado foi diferente do esperado? Precisamos saber o que você tentou e onde está o calo.

Comment: O calo está na parte onde não sei como calcular o momento exato que cada círculo vai colidir com o outro juntamente com a parte de como vou fazer para seguirem tal direção.

Comment: @Marpd144 Edite a pergunta e acrescente isso lá, se possível explicando melhor o que você já fez com código, já tentou e etc. Isso ajuda o pessoal a entender seu problema e a ajudá-lo.

Answer (score 12):

Pelo que parece o problema é mais para verificar as colisões.
Uma forma **simples**, é verificar se a distância entre as partículas é menor que a soma dos raios delas:

[image: Distância entre Centros]

Algo do tipo:

```
dist < (p1.r() + p2.r())
```

Se isso for verdadeiro é porque a partícula `p1` colidiu com `p2`.

A partir daí você calcula a colisão entre as partículas. Se você for fazer algo realístico, você deve dar uma estudada em [Momento Linear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum). Se você considerar que elas tem a mesma massa, fica mais simples.

---

Baseando, no código que você postou você pode verificar a colisão dessa forma:

```
float temp_x, temp_y, dist;

for(int i = 0 ; i<n ; ++i)
{
    Particula& p1 = m_particulas[i];

    for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
    {
        if(i == j)
        {
            // Não verifica colisão entre a mesma partícula.
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            // Verifica se a distância entre duas partículas é menor que 2.diametro,
            // se for é porque colidiu.
            Particula& p2 = m_particulas[j];

            temp_x = p2.x() - p1.x();
            temp_y = p2.y() - p1.y();

            dist = std::sqrt(temp_x * temp_x + temp_y * temp_y);

            if(dist < (p1.r() + p2.r()))
            {
                // Colidiram.
                // Nesse caso, elas devem mudar de direção.

                // Inverta a velocidade ou faça um metodo para colisão mais realístico.

                if(temp_x > temp_y)
                {
                    p1.invVx();
                    p2.invVx();
                }
                else
                {
                    p1.invVy();
                    p2.invVy();
                }                    

                break;
            }
        }
    }

    m_particulas[i].andar();
}
```

Existem formas mais eficientes de verificar a colisão entre as partículas, mas essa é uma bem **simples** e que deve ajudar a resolver seu problema.

Se quiser se aprofundar um pouco mais, esse [link](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Archived:Calculating_ball_collision_physics_in_Flash_Lite) possui uma implementação semelhante, porém mais realista, considerando a massa das partículas e tudo.

Em C++, a versão apresentada pelo link fica assim:

```
void Particula::colidir(Particula& p1, Particula& p2)
{
    // diferença entre as distâncias em x e y
    double dx = p1.x() - p2.x();
    double dy = p1.y() - p2.y();

    // angulo de colisão
    double col_angle = std::atan2(dy, dx);

    // módulo da velocidade
    double V1 = p1.velocity();
    double V2 = p2.velocity();

    // ângulo da direção
    double direction1 = std::atan2(p1.vy(), p1.vx());
    double direction2 = std::atan2(p2.vy(), p2.vx());

    // joga os cálculos para uma única dimesão para realizar
    // os cálculos.
    double vx_1 = V1 * std::cos(direction1 - col_angle);
    double vy_1 = V1 * std::sin(direction1 - col_angle);
    double vx_2 = V2 * std::cos(direction2 - col_angle);
    double vy_2 = V2 * std::sin(direction2 - col_angle);

    // calcula a velocidade final, considerando a massa das partículas.
    double final_vx_1 = ((p1.mass() - p2.mass()) * vx_1 + (p2.mass() + p2.mass()) * vx_2)/(p1.mass() + p2.mass());
    double final_vx_2 = ((p1.mass() + p1.mass()) * vx_1 + (p2.mass() - p1.mass()) * vx_2)/(p1.mass() + p2.mass());
    double final_vy_1 = vy_1;
    double final_vy_2 = vy_2;

    // retorna os cálculos para o 2d
    const double PI2 = 1.57079632679489661923132169163;
    p1.m_vx = std::cos(col_angle) * final_vx_1 + std::cos(col_angle + PI2) * final_vy_1;
    p1.m_vy = std::sin(col_angle) * final_vx_1 + std::sin(col_angle + PI2) * final_vy_1;
    p2.m_vx = std::cos(col_angle) * final_vx_2 + std::cos(col_angle + PI2) * final_vy_2;
    p2.m_vy = std::sin(col_angle) * final_vx_2 + std::sin(col_angle + PI2) * final_vy_2;
}
```

No entanto, deve-se ressaltar que para esse algoritmo ainda não cobre duas situações:

1. Partículas que se movem muito rápido: a cada passo do cálculo elas podem se deslocar mais do que os cálculos de detecção de colisão preveem e com isso "atravessar" as demais (esse problema é tratado pelo [box2d](http://box2d.org/), com uma algoritmo especial (só pesquisar por `bullet`).
2. Quando as partículas são aleatoriamente (durante o loading) postas uma dentro da outra.

---

Outro detalhe: No seu programa, quando você desenha a partícula, você usar uma borda de 5 pixels. Remova essa borda ou some ela ao raio pois ela influi no visualização da colisão.

Comment: Tentarei fazer o que você sugeriu e volto com uma resposta.
Muito obrigado.

Comment: Editei adicionando a forma como eu testei aqui. Mas eu removi a borda de 5px, pois ela muda o raio e influencia nos cálculos. E `invVx()` é o método que inverte a velocidade em x.

Comment: Seria bacana traduzir o texto da imagem e, principalmente, utilizar as mesmas referências de valores (`p1.r()` ao invés de `r1`, por exemplo).

Comment: Concordo. Vou fazer isso.

Answer (score 9):

Você pode investigar as seguintes classes do Qt pra realizar esta tarefa por você:

- [`QGraphicsScene`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsscene.html)
- [`QGraphicsItem`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html)

As duas classes em conjunto oferecem recursos para detecção de colisão, conforme demonstrado no exemplo do [Colliding Mice](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/graphicsview-collidingmice.html):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O exemplo utiliza `QGraphicsScene::collidingItems()` para verificar se houve colisões entre os ratinhos.

Comment: Ajudou bastante, @karlphillip. Brigadão, man.